# Rails calling a controller from another model's view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, helper, link-to

I have a `post` model and an `upvote` model.

`upvote.rb`

```
class Upvote < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user
  belongs_to :post
end
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: upvotes
#
#  id         :integer         not null, primary key
#  user_id    :integer
#  post_id    :integer
#  comment    :text
#  created_at :datetime
#  updated_at :datetime
#
```

Now within `posts/index` I want to add an upvote for the current user and the post.

Some research pointed me to write a helper
`posts_helper.rb`

```
module PostsHelper
  def upvote_post(post)
    @upvote = Upvote.new
    @upvote.user_id = current_user.id
    @upvote.post_id = post.id
    if @upvote.save
     flash.now[:notice] = 'Upvote was successfully created.'
    end
  end
end
```

Inside my view I want to call the helper only on clicking a link but can't seem to get `link_to` working properly.

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to "upboats" upvote_post(post) %></td>
    <td><%= post.name %></td>
...
```

I get the error `syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')'` and can't seem to find any good alternatives.

What am I missing here?

---

**UPDATED**

It was a comma. *facepalm*

Plenty of other issues, but that was what led to the error.

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to "upboats", upvote_post(post) %></td>
    <td><%= post.name %></td>
...
```

Comment: A comma, you're missing a comma. And your helper smells like a controller.

Comment: In retrospect it ought to be a controller.  I'm just hacking on 0 sleep.

Comment: Arguable.  Definitely lower than average though.

Comment: And don't forget to add an answer and accept it later, so that others may skip your (now open) question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing open question.

It was a comma.

---

UPDATED

It was a comma. facepalm

Plenty of other issues, but that was what led to the error.

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to "upboats", upvote_post(post) %></td>
    <td><%= post.name %></td>
...
```